# Node.js with express routing and sub routing

Tags: node.js, express, url-routing

I am playing with node.js and I don't quite understand why something I set up is working in one instance but if I make a slight change it will not work in another instance.

in my app.js I have

```
app.use('/musicplayer',  require('./routes/music/index'));
```

in my music\index.js I have

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.use('/users', require('./users'));

module.exports = router;
```

in my users.js I have this - **working version**

```
var express = require('express');
var usersRouter = express.Router();
var sqllite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

usersRouter.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('music/login', { title: 'Express' });
});
module.exports = usersRouter;
```

But I would like to encapsulate the routes I am defining into another function like this **not working** this just hangs the page.

Modified version of my users.js **not working**

```
var express = require('express');
var usersRouter = express.Router();
var sqllite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

var router = function () {
    usersRouter.get('/login', function (req, res, next) {
        res.render('music/login', {title: 'Express'});
    });
    return usersRouter;
}
module.exports = router;
```

In the console I can see it comes in tries the get and nevers gets routed I see this "GET /musicplayer/users/login - - ms - -".

I have even put a console.log right before the return in the anonymous function I created to know it is getting in there and that I am hooking the pathways up right from the parent routes.  And I do hit that log action to the screen.

Any help or tips would be appreciated:)

PS in case you are wondering I am trying to separate out apps for different development work I want to play with.  So that is why I am doing the sub routing with musicplayer/index.js instead of just putting everything in the app.js for declaring of my main routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Router.use()` expects an instance of another `Router`. However your (non-working) module only returns a function.

Use this in your index.js to fix the issue:

```
router.use('/users', require('./users')());
```

Comment: Thanks so much that worked... I was treating it like a callback which I guess it isn't.....